# ¿Cómo puedo validar un input de tipo número, para que solo se puedan introducir números entre 0 y 100?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy trabajando con un formulario, y quiero que este input solo se pueda llenar con un número entre 0 y 100. El problema es que igual permite cualquier número, positivo, negativo, de 5 dígitos, de uno

```
<input
  type="number" style="resize: none;" class="form-control is-invalid requerido"
  rows="2" id="txt_area_avancePorcentaje" name="porcentajeAvance"
  min="0" max="100" maxlength="3"
  placeholder="Digite un número entre 0 y 100 para el porcentaje de avance..."
/>
```

Ahí le he intentado poner maxlength para solo permitir tres dígitos pero aun así no me funcionó. Estoy trabajando con html, javascript y JQuery.
Me permite numeros de cuantos digitos sea (quiero que sea máximo 3) y que estos sean entre 0 y 100 exclusivamente pero ya no sé cómo más hacerlo

Comment: Buenos días. Disculpeme, estaba probando otras cosas y lo hice sin querer jajaja. Ahorita lo volví a poner. Su respuesta fue la que me funcionó. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El atributo `maxlength` en los input tipo `number` no funcionan porque su objetivo es limitar la longitud de una entrada de **texto** y no el valor **numérico** en el input. Podrías implementar una lógica para que funcione el `maxlength`, usando el atributo `oninput`:

```html
<input
  type="number"
  oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
  maxlength="3" required
/>
```

Como verás, solo podemos digitar hasta 3 números como máximo, ya que si superamos la longitud del `maxlenth`, ocurre el `slice` (o sea, se borra el caracter, en donde ya no nos permite digitar más).

---

Ahora, el objetivo es que no se puedan digitar números negativos y mayores a `100`, podrías validar en el mismo `oninput`. Aquí simplemente estoy validando que si el valor que digito en el input es mayor a `100` y menor a `0`, ocurrirá el `slice`, ejemplo:

```html
<input
  type="number"
  oninput="javascript: 
    if (this.value > 100 || this.value < 0) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.value.length - 1);
    if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
  maxlength="3"
  required
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes Utilizar el evento **oninput** en JavaScript este es un evento que se activa cuando el usuario introduce o modifica el valor de un elemento de formulario

```js
 const inputNumber = document.getElementById('inputNumber');

  function validateInput() {
    if (inputNumber.value < 0 || inputNumber.value > 100) {
      inputNumber.setCustomValidity('El número debe estar entre 0 y 100');
    } else {
      inputNumber.setCustomValidity('numero correcto');
    }
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    Input de número:
    <input type="number" id="inputNumber" min="0" max="100" oninput="validateInput()" required>
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Creo que el OP se refiere a que no quiere que le permita escribir números mayores a 100 y menores a 0. Esa validación que muestras ya le funcionaba con el atributo *min* y *max*...